# Universal Clipboard, Receive Calls Simultaneously, and Available Personal Hotspot aren't working

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-m1, macos-ventura

What I have:

- iPhone 11 Pro Max is running iOS 16.5.
- MacBook Pro M1 Pro is running Ventura 13.4.

*The following features aren't working:*

- Universal Clipboard
- Receive calls simultaneously on iPhone and MacBook
- Available Personal Hotspot while **Allow Others to Join** is disabled.

*What I tried:*

- Turning on and off both Bluetooth and WiFi on both devices
- Turning on and off **Allow Handoff** on both devices
- Singing out and in on both devices

*What worked:*

- Signing out and in on the MacBook. However, the problems reappear after a day or two.

*What I'm aiming for:*
That all the features I listed above will work again